# std::map: return vectors consisting of keys that have equal values

Tags: c++, algorithm, dictionary, duplicates, stdmap

I have a `std::map` object. Keys are entity IDs (integers) and values their 2D positions (vectors). The aim is to identify, which entities are in the 
same position.

```
ID  Position
1   {2,3}
5   {6,2}
12  {2,3}
54  {4,4}
92  {6,2}
```

I need to get a vector of vectors consisting of keys, which have equal values.

Output for the example input data above: {1,12}, {5,92}

I know I can copy the 2D positions to vector to vectors and loop the first level vector to find indexes of equal second level vectors. Then work back to find keys by selecting the vectors by index and looping again to find the corresponding keys.

Please suggest a cleaner approach for this.

Comment: provide some of your code please

Answer (score 6):

The point of an `std::map` is to provide an efficient **key to value** mapping. What you need is an additional **value to key** mapping - that can be achieved in multiple ways:

- Have with an extra `std::map` that goes from `Position` to `std::vector<ID>`.
- Use some sort of *spatial partitioning* data structure *(e.g. quadtree, spatial hash, grid)* that makes it efficient to find entities depending on their position.
- Use a **bidirectional multi-map** like [`boost::bimap`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/boost_bimap/the_tutorial/controlling_collection_types.html). This will allow you to have a bidirectional mapping over collection of values without having to use multiple data structures.

> "How do I choose?"

It depends on your priorities. If you want maximum performance, you should try all the approaches *(maybe using some sort of templatized wrapper)* and profile. If you want elegance/cleanliness, `boost::bimap` seems to be the most appropriate solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could put your data from the map into a `std::mutlimap`, with the `Position` as key and `ID` as value.

As a side note I wonder if a `std::pair` might be better than a vector for 2d points.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide a reverse mapping. There are a number of ways to do this, including `multimap`, but a simple approach if your mapping isn't modified after creation is to iterate over the map and build up the reverse mapping. In the reverse mapping, you map value -> list of keys.

The code below uses `std::unordered_map` to map `std::pair<int, int>` (the value in the original map) to `std::vector<int>` (list of keys in the original map). The building of the reverse map is simple and concise:

```
std::unordered_map<Point, std::vector<int>, hash> r;
for (const auto& item : m) {
    r[item.second].push_back(item.first);
}
```

(See the full example for the definition of `hash`).

There's no need to worry about whether the key exists; it will be created (and the vector of ids will be initialised as an empty vector) when you attempt to access that key using the `r[key]` notation.

This solution targets simplicity; it's a workable solution if you need to do this and don't care about performance, memory usage or using third-party libraries like Boost.

If you do care about any of those things, or you're modifying the map while doing lookups in both directions, you should probably explore other options.

---

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6ff19e0ed0049e8b)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>

// Define a point type. Use pair<int, int> for simplicity.
using Point = std::pair<int, int>;

// Define a hash function for our point type:
struct hash {
    std::size_t operator()(const Point& p) const 
    {
        std::size_t h1 = std::hash<int>{}(p.first);
        std::size_t h2 = std::hash<int>{}(p.second);
        return h1 ^ (h2 << 1);
    }
};

int main() {
    // The original forward mapping:
    std::map<int, Point> m = {
        {1, {2, 3}},
        {5, {6, 2}},
        {12, {2, 3}},
        {54, {4, 4}},
        {92, {6, 2}}
    };

    // Build reverse mapping:
    std::unordered_map<Point, std::vector<int>, hash> r;
    for (const auto& item : m) {
        r[item.second].push_back(item.first);
    }

    // DEMO: Show all indices for {6, 2}:
    Point val1 = {6, 2};
    for (const auto& id : r[val1]) {
        std::cout << id << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";

    // DEMO: Show all indices for {2, 3}:
    Point val2 = {2, 3};
    for (const auto& id : r[val2]) {
        std::cout << id << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42132982/3919155) seems to be best, but I'll offer my code anyway.

Given

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

// Some definiton of Vector2D
struct Vector2D { int x; int y; };

// and some definition of operator< on Vector2D
bool operator<(Vector2D const & a, Vector2D const & b) noexcept {
    if (a.x < b.x) return true;
    if (a.x > b.x) return false;
    return a.y < b.y;
}
```

How about:

```
template <typename M>
auto calculate(M const & inputMap) -> std::vector<std::vector<typename M::key_type> > {
    std::map<typename M::mapped_type,
            std::vector<typename M::key_type> > resultMap;
    for (auto const & vp : inputMap)
        resultMap[vp.second].push_back(vp.first);
    std::vector<std::vector<typename M::key_type> > result;
    for (auto & vp: resultMap)
        if (vp.second.size() > 1)
            result.emplace_back(std::move(vp.second));
    return result;
}
```

Here's how to test:

```
int main() {
    std::map<int, Vector2D> input{
        {1,  Vector2D{2,3}},
        {5,  Vector2D{6,2}},
        {13, Vector2D{2,3}},
        {54, Vector2D{4,4}},
        {92, Vector2D{6,2}}
    };

    auto const result = calculate(input);

    // Ugly print
    std::cout << '{';
    static auto const maybePrintComma =
        [](bool & print) {
            if (print) {
                std::cout << ", ";
            } else {
                print = true;
            }
        };
    bool comma = false;
    for (auto const & v: result) {
        maybePrintComma(comma);
        std::cout << '{';
        bool comma2 = false;
        for (auto const & v2: v) {
            maybePrintComma(comma2);
            std::cout << v2;
        }
        std::cout << '}';
    }
    std::cout << '}' << std::endl;
}
```